# Find the indices in a multi dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following numpy array:

```
ar = np.array([[(1,2),2],[(2,3),"hi"],[(3,3,3),"bye"],[(1,2),2]])
```

I would like to get the indices of `[(1,2),2]` (0 and 3 should be the output)

I tried with `np.where` but it is not working well

Does anyone know an efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Where does such an array come from?  It's a mix bag of values, some number, some tuples, some strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
np.where(np.all(ar == [(1,2),2], axis=1))
```

That is, find the locations equal to `[(1,2),2]`, turn the 2D result into 1D using AND, and do `where` to convert the boolean mask to numeric indices.

Comment: This just tests the 1st column, `(1,2)`.  `np.where((ar == [(1,2),'boo'])[:,0])`  produces the same `[0,3]`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `where` is complicated by the fact that the elements of `ar` are a mixed bag (number, tuples and strings), hence the `object` dtype.  Shape is (4,2)

```
In [41]: ar = np.array([[(1,2),2],[(2,3),"hi"],[(3,3,3),"bye"],[(1,2),2]])
In [42]: ar
Out[42]: 
array([[(1, 2), 2],
       [(2, 3), 'hi'],
       [(3, 3, 3), 'bye'],
       [(1, 2), 2]], dtype=object)
```

It works to compare it with a 1 row array (a list):

```
In [43]: ar==[(1,2),2]
Out[43]: 
array([[ True,  True],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

`where` just gives the indices of the True values in this boolean array

```
In [44]: np.where(ar==[(1,2),2])
Out[44]: (array([0, 0, 3, 3]), array([0, 1, 0, 1]))
```

Or since you want the row where both values match, add a `np.all`

```
In [62]: np.where(np.all(ar==[(1,2),2],1))
Out[62]: (array([0, 3]),)
```

In this case, using an array has little value over a list of lists:

```
In [53]: arl=ar.tolist()
In [54]: arl.index([(1,2),2])
Out[54]: 0
In [56]: arl.index([(1,2),2],1)
Out[56]: 3
```

---

Usually object dtype arrays appear in complex dtypes, ones with several fields.  For example if we define a composite dtype with 2 fields:

```
dt2 = np.dtype([('1st','O'),('2nd','O')])
```

and change the `ar` value so it is a list of tuples (rather than list of lists)

```
ar1 = [((1, 2), 2), ((2, 3), 'hi'), ((3, 3, 3), 'bye'), ((1, 2), 2)]
arr = np.array(ar1,dt2)
```

the resulting array has shape (4,), with each element being a composite (displayed as a tuple):

```
array([((1, 2), 2), ((2, 3), 'hi'), ((3, 3, 3), 'bye'), ((1, 2), 2)], 
    dtype=[('1st', 'O'), ('2nd', 'O')])
```

This can be tested with:

```
arr==np.array(((1,2),2), dt2)
# array([ True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

And the corresponding where is:

```
np.where(arr==np.array(((1,2),2), dt2))
# (array([0, 3]),)
```